# How to catch event on clicking the link in webBrowser in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I am making a Windows Phone 7 api (i.e. .dll file), which is bringing ads from the server in a `webBrowser`. The ads coming into `webBrowser` are animated.

The `webBrowser` has a dynamic html which contains a link (i.e. `strClickStr`) and an image link (i.e. `strAdURL`).  There are various images on the server and each image has different link attached with it like audio link, video link and an url link.

Till now everything is working but when I click on the ad, the link attached with it should call. If it is audio/video link then it should play in default audio/video player and if it is url then it should open in default `webBrowser`.

This is my html right now for url to open in default webBrowser:

```
var adx_strHtml = (
    new StringBuilder("<html><body bgcolor='#000000'><a target='_blank' href="))
    .Append(adx_strClickStr)
    .Append("><img width='100%' height='10%' onerror='imageLoadFailed()' src='")
    .Append(adx_strAdURL)
    .Append("' alt='' />")
    .Append("</a></body></html>")
    .ToString();
```

Now my question is how should I catch the event on clicking the ad and check the link and perform the particular task?

Answer (score 3):

You can handle the [WebBrowser.Navigating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigating%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) event and use the [NavigatingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.navigatingeventargs%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) object to get the `Uri` and/or `Cancel` the event.